# What is wrong with the syntax of this CREATE TRIGGER statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `lastedited` AFTER UPDATE ON `eng-jap`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`eng` 
SET `lastmodified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `eng`.`english` = old.eng;
UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`jap` 
SET `lastmodified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `jap`.`japanese` = old.jap;
END;
```

The error returned by MySQL is:
MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: are you sure that there is no syntax error on typing your tables names? , seems that japanese is error

Comment: 100% sure that the table and column names are correct

Comment: if i remove the BEGIN and END as well as one of the update statments it works, but i need both updates to be in the trigger

Comment: try this : where eng.english = {old.eng} twice

Comment: I'm not sure of this but I think using a "-" on table names is not a good idea even on columns have never tried that before but my guess is the problem begins from there try to rename your table perhaps and run this query again using this query rename "eng-jap" to "engjap" instead.

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo if he put the table name between ` ` , then - doesn't matter

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo and then the error will be something like missing something near to -JAP

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I see but I think nothing is wrong if he tries it though

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo see my answer , i thing it works with him

Comment: @WilliamKinaan yup thanks for pointing that out. you have a good sight to see that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#START TRIGGER
    delimiter $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `lastedited` AFTER UPDATE ON `eng-jap`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`eng` 
    SET `lastmodified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `eng`.`english` = old.eng;
    UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`jap` 
    SET `lastmodified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `jap`.`japanese` = old.jap;
    END;
    $$
```

if it still not working , try to replace your old.eng and old.jap with static values such as "roma"

Comment: William Kinaan's solution worked! though i still dont know why it didnt work how I wrote it. Nor do i understand yet what he did to fix it...

Comment: yes it worked. I just dont understand why it didn't work the way I wrote it

Comment: @user1397417 delimiter $$ -> this statement changes the delimiter of your database cause when you run the create trigger statement the default delimiter is being used for identifying the closing of your statement which is the ";" so MySQL would get confused for which statement the delimiter should be used to close the whole query so changing the delimiter to "$$" would help MySQL identify that your already closing the "CREATE TRIGGER" statement. :)